# In tensorflow, why slim.data.set.Dataset requires `num_samples`? Is there any way to use it without knowing `num_samples`?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying TFrecords using slim.dataset.Dataset example.

```
slim.dataset.Dataset(
        data_sources=file_pattern,
        reader=reader,
        decoder=decoder,
        num_samples=SPLITS_TO_SIZES[split_name],
        items_to_descriptions=ITEMS_TO_DESCRIPTIONS,
        num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
        labels_to_names=labels_to_names)
```

Later I am going to use this as in

```
provider = dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset, shuffle=False)
```

I am wondering why the Dataset requires num_samples. E.g., what if one provided a pre-complied **kitti_val.tfrecord**?

From the KITTI dataset definition, I may be able to set other arguments such as `num_classes`, `labels_to_names`, etc. However, I may not know how many samples the `val` split would have (it could be 10% or 20% of the training set.)

Moreover, I am guessing that `num_samples` could possibly and be calculated internally, and be deterministic.

Is there any way to use pre-complied tfrecord without knowing `num_samples`?

Comment: In another related question: if I encode my custom split into `kitti_train1.tfrecord`, should I keep its `num_samples` i,e, how many training examples I encoded with?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a way to use tfrecord and num_samples?